# audiokit akparameter automated manipulation

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit, akoscillator

I followed the oscillator model and setup akparameters the same way, which are easily manipulated with realtime controls. How can I manipulate a parameter using an LFO or envelope for example: make the amplitude modulate while the key is pressed? I have been trying to find the answer for weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Look into AKOperations.  There are playgrounds for them that should explain how to use them (see Operations section of http://audiokit.io/playgrounds/Synthesis/) , but basically any operation can be fed into another one so you get sample accurate control of whatever parameter you want.  Alternatively, you can also dive into modulating parameters at the DSP level in C or C++, which we do in our synths.